# Is the argument for approaching of an approximated quantity to its true value sound?

Tags: calculus, limits, logic

Consider a quantity, $a$, which could represent various measures such as the area under a curve. Initially, we estimate the value of $a$. As we refine our approximation, we find that we can make it arbitrarily close to a number $\ell$. This suggests that $a$ equals $\ell$. But why is this the case?

Here's the rationale:

Suppose, for contradiction, that $a$ does not equal $\ell$, but instead equals a different number, say $m$. In the process of approximating $a$, it should approach $m$ (or in other words, we find that we can make it arbitrarily close to $m$), as $m$ is its true value. However, $a$ is approaching $\ell$ (Because we said that we can make it arbitrarily close to a number $\ell$), and this is a contradiction. Therefore, the actual value of $a$ must be $\ell$, as any other assumption leads to a contradiction.

Is this reasoning sound?

---

**Edit:** According to Charles Hudgins's comment, my reasoning wasn't sound and as I understood, the sound proof is as follows:

1. $a$ can get arbitrarily close.
2. $\therefore$ $a$ can get $\frac{|a - \ell|}{2}$ close.
3. So now $|a - \ell|$ (The distance between $a$ and $\ell$) must be smaller or equal to $\frac{|a-\ell|}{2}$.
4. $\therefore$ $|a - \ell| \leq \frac{|a-\ell|}{2}\implies |a - \ell| = 0\implies \color{red}{\boxed{\color{black}{a = \ell}}}$

Now did I understand correctly?

Comment: No, because the negation of $a \to \ell$ is not $a \to m$ for some other number $m$. The classic argument is instead to say that $a$ can get arbitrarily close, so it can get $\frac{|a - \ell|}{2}$ close. But then $|a - \ell| \leq \frac{|a-\ell|}{2}$, which can only happen if $|a - \ell| = 0$, i.e. $a = \ell$.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins As I understood, the sound proof is as follows:

$a$ can get arbitrarily close, therefore, $a$ can get $\frac{|a - \ell|}{2}$ close.
So now $|a - \ell|$ (The distance between $a$ and $\ell$) must be smaller or equal to $\frac{|a-\ell|}{2}$.
Therefore $|a - \ell| \leq \frac{|a-\ell|}{2}\implies |a - \ell| = 0\implies \color{red}{\boxed{\color{black}{a = \ell}}}$

Now did I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. Your proof is more like the proof that limits are unique, which is a slightly different idea, but maybe what you intended. My proof shows that there's no way a number can be arbitrarily close to another number without in fact being that number.

Comment: And I was a little sloppy for expediency. Really we should go through contradiction. Suppose $a\neq\ell$, then half the distance between them is a strictly positive distance, which a and $\ell$ must be closer than, a contradiction. The issue with my proof is that the distance may be $0$, in which case the argument doesn't work (but hopefully it's easy to see that in such a case we are already done).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness, here is the proof I poorly outlined in the comments. Suppose $|a - \ell| < \epsilon$ for every $\epsilon > 0$. This formalizes the notion that $a$ and $\ell$ are arbitrarily close.

Suppose, for contradiction, that $a \neq \ell$. Then $\frac{|a - \ell|}{2} > 0$. But, taking $\epsilon = \frac{|a - \ell|}{2} > 0$, this means $|a - \ell| < \frac{|a - \ell|}{2}$, i.e. $\frac{|a - \ell|}{2} < 0$, a contradiction. We conclude $a = \ell$.

Note to the interested reader: It is crucial that this proof requires contradiction because there are ways of formulating math that reject proof by contradiction and consequently permit numbers which are arbitrarily close but nevertheless distinct.

Comment: Thank you so much. But a question has occupied my mind. Suppose that we define a function $f(x)$ in a way that it is everywhere $2x$ except at the point $x=6$. At $x=6$, we define $f(6) = 10$. With your proof, we can prove that $f(6)=2(6)=12$. It's because, $f(x)$ can get arbitrarily close to the number $12$. So $f(x)=12$, but according to our definition, the function $f(x)$ is never equal to $12$. What is the issue?

Comment: Note that $f$ is a function, not a number. The analogous statement would be $f(6)$ is arbitrarily close to $12$, but it isn't by construction. For this reason, we say that $f$ is not continuous.

Comment: You can maybe think about it like this. A function can "move" so it can get arbitrarily close to a value without actually attaining the value (unless it is continuous). By contrast, a number is fixed in place, so the only way it can be arbitrarily close to a value is by actually being equal to that value.

Answer (score 0):

What you have done in that first part is argue the logic behind definition of the limit. However, I would argue the beginning logic is slightly flawed. Imagine if I consider the sequence $x_n$=$\frac {1}{n}$. Obviously $x_n->0 $ as $n->\infty$, but $x_n$ never becomes zero, so $x_n$ will never "equal" zero as you have written.

The actual proof for that statement is explained in the comments well by Charles Hudgins (and for the record, that is probably the way you should look at this proof), I recommend you look at that!